# pubnub error - "use of undeclared indentifier" in pubnub and ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, pubnub

I'm new in IOS, I am compiling a project and I have the following error:
[image: err]

```
+(PNConfiguration*)getDefaultConfiguration
{
   return [PNConfiguration configurationWithPublishKey:kPMDPubNubPublisherKey subscribeKey:kPMDPubNubSubcriptionKey secretKey:@""];
}
```

> Error:(50, 56) use of undeclared identifier 'kPMDPubNubPublisherKey'

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant code and the exact error message. Be sure to point out which line is causing the error.

Comment: No, update your question with your code. Copy and paste the actual text into your question (and be sure your format it properly).

Comment: Perhaps there is another .h file you need to import - one that declares those two constants.

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem, needed an importation where these variables were defined.

Comment: Please add your answer as "an answer" to this thread. And by the way, I see you are using the constructor with the ```secretKey``` parameter so this must be PubNub iOS SDK 3.x. If possible, you should be using the 4.1.1 SDK. If you must be on 3.x, make sure you are on the last release - 3.7.11. But move to 4.1.1 (or whatever is latest 4.x) as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was that import statements were missing where the references to the variables were.